# Gatling scala: I have a multiple csv files, and want to use them for the POST Call sequentially ,how to process multiple csv files using gatling?

Tags: csv, gatling

Gatling: I have a multiple csv files, and want to use them for the POST Call sequentially or randomly using scala, and each csv file should be processed only once.

i expect both these csv files to be processed and make a POST request, and all records from both csv files should be processed only once, and each csv file also should also be processsed only once.

Can you please advise how to get this done and if there are any other solutions that can address the issue here?

here is the code and CSV files i have.

```
R-1.csv

empNo, slotNo
13648,[49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 1-3-5-7]
24824,[52 51 53 50 37 36 38]

R-2.csv

empNo, slotNo
23241,[48 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 1-4-5-7]
09344,[59 51 53 50 37 36 38]
```

```scala
val bidSlots_feeder1 = List(csv("data/R-1.csv"),csv("data/R-2.csv"))


 def bidSubmission(): ChainBuilder =
    pause(pauseBy(5) seconds)
      .repeat(2) {
       //  feed(bidSlots_feeder1). --> compile time error
          .exec(postToUri(s"${Constants.bidSubmission_URL}/#{$AuctionId}/base-orders/proxy-bid", s"Submit bids for : #{$AuctionId}")
            .queryParam("employeeId", "#{empNo}")
            .body(StringBody(session => {
              println(session)
              println(session.attributes("empNo"))
              val empNo = session.attributes("empNo").asInstanceOf[String]
              val slotNo = session.attributes("slotNo").asInstanceOf[String]
              val auctionId = session.attributes("AuctionId").asInstanceOf[String]
              println(s"\n\n\n ${Constants.bidSubmission_URL}/$auctionId/base-orders/proxy-bid \n\n\n")
              println(s"\n\n\n $slotNo \n\n\n")
              var slotNos = slotNo.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(" +")
              println(s"\n\n\n ${generatePayload(empNo, slotNos, auctionId)} \n\n\n")
              generatePayload(empNo, slotNos, auctionId)
            }))
          )
      }



  private def generatePayload(empNo: String, slotNos: Array[String], auctionId: String) = {
    s"""
       | {
       |    "submittedAt": ${DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(OffsetDateTime.now)}
       |    "allowSameMonth": false,
       |    "allowConsecutiveMonths": true,
       |    "selections": [
                 ${generateSlotNo(slotNos, auctionId)}
       |    ]
       |}
       |""".stripMargin
  }

  private def generateSlotNo(slotNos: Array[String], Id: String) = {
    slotNos.map(slotNo => s"\"${Constants.proxySubmission_URL}/${Id}/base/00000-00000-00000/order-slots/${slotNo}\"").mkString(",")
  }
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is unclear. Are you trying to merge to 2 files?

Comment: no, i want to process each file R-1.csv and R2.csv files separately. I want to read R-1.csv file ,generate the paylaod for the two records from R-1.csv file, make a POST request, and next read R-2.csv file, ,and generate the paylaod for the two records from R-2.csv file, make a POST request..

Comment: def pickRandomEntryFromList(list: List[Any]): Any = list.foreach( list => {
    println
    return list
  }) , I added pickRandomEntryFromList custom method, and added this line in the code above in the feeder like below,  feed(pickRandomEntryFromList(bidSlots_feeder1).asInstanceOf[BatchableFeederBuilder[String]]). but it chooses only one csv file out of two, and the other file is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is a prepare your data **before** the load. You can make it easier than try use Gatling for this. Here you are simple script for merge two csv:

```bash
paste -d '\n' R-1.csv R-2.csv | sed '1d' > new.csv
```

---

Explanation:

1. `paste -d '\n' R-1.csv R-2.csv` it combines two csv into the one. And records will be written **in turn**
2. `sed '1d'` for remove duplicate headers

Comment: Hi @Amerousful, Can i use the following code to merge csv files in scala? paste -d '\n' R-1.csv R-2.csv | sed '1d' > new.csv

Comment: You can do this without scala. Just use console, it'll be simpler.

Comment: But still, if you insist, so here you are: 
```import sys.process._ 
"pwd".!
```

Comment: sorry not sure if i understood, would like to merge the code inside scala class (where i have my gatling code) , when you say console, can i use the code above inside shell script file and execute? how i can store the merged file to a project path once it is merged? , also can you please explain if i should add this line as a import statement in scala, if i want to do with scala import sys.process._  "pwd".!   , and wondering what is the use of the import

Comment: @Banu Yes, you can use this code inside your shell script. And then just pass `new.csv` into `feed`

Comment: ok, @Amerousful, Can you please clarify how i can make use of new.csv file from shell script in my gatling list, wondering how i can import (how gatling test can access new.csv file), and is there a way to shuffle csv rows while merging the two files?

Comment: @Banu https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/feeder/#csv-feeders

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!, I am aware of csv feeder in gatling , that shuffles the record. and paste command you provided is really helpful, and like you said it adds records in turn, is there a way to shuffle the records (instead of 'in turn) while merging the files?  In my gatling scenario use case, we want to process each row only once -hence i cant use csv feeder shuffle logic(shuffle logic might end up processing the same record twice i believe, please correct me if i am wrong). Hence I would like to shuffle the records using paste command even before injecting into my gatling test

Comment: @Banu Nope, `shuffle` has the same behavior like an `queue`

Comment: Thank you, I will use shuffle in my case, and i noticed while merging two csv rows, it is inserting empty rows, when the first CSV file has 581 rows, and the second csv file has 134 rows it adds empty records while inserting records in turn, can you please advise how to get rid of empty rows?

Comment: @Banu Sorry, but I provided enough information about your question

Comment: Thank you @ Amerousful, your recommendation is indeed helpful. and I would like to also shuffle the individual columns of the CSV (instead of csv rows), is this possible using shell command? This is is link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631807/is-there-a-way-to-shuffle-csv-columns-within-the-single-csv-file-using-shell-com , Can you please assist?