# Is there a way to shuffle csv columns (instead of shuffling CSV Rows) within the single csv file using shell command?

Tags: csv, shuffle

**Shuffle csv columns (instead of shuffling CSV rows)**
I am looking for an option (possibly shell command) **to shuffle only one column of CSV** and keep the other CSV column unchanged. Can you please advise if it is possible by any means?

```
 CSV File:
    R3.csv
    orderNo, id
    67982,[89 55 12]
    13230,[45 12 11]
    13523,[31 67 12]
    19821,[12 9 8]
```

I would like to change the sequence or orderNo and produce the CSV file with a new order( any shuffled order) and keep the id column value as it is, using the shell command.

**Option 1:**
I would like to shuffle **the Individual column** in the above CSV file into any of the following ways listed below.

```
Modified csv file
R3.csv
orderNo, id
13523,[89 55 12]
67982,[45 12 11]
13230,[31 67 12]
19821,[12 9 8]
```

**Option 2:**
(or) a shell command to change the sequence of id **column order** and keep orderNo value as it is.(any shuffled order)

```
Modified csv file
R3.csv
orderNo, id
67982,[31 67 12]
13230,[89 55 12]
13523,[12 9 8]
19821,[45 12 11]
```

**Option 3:**
(or) a bash command to have **the both the columns shuffled.**

eg:

```
 Modified csv file
    R3.csv
    orderNo, id
    13523,[45 12 11]
    67982,[12 9 8]
    13230,[89 55 12]
    19821,[31 67 12]
```

Comment: So go ahead and shuffle the files before you paste them.

Comment: that is my question, not sure how i can shuffle the files (shuffle the csv column values) like the way i wanted using shell command. can you please advise?

Comment: My point is that instead of trying to shuffle csv files, just shuffle the original files before you create the csv. The csv is not involved. (If you knew that, then why did you ask how to shuffle a csv?)

Comment: I guess my question is not clear. I updated my question, I want to shuffle the records of a single CSV file (R3.CSV) and produce the new single csv file (modified csv file) with the shuffled records - provided three examples, if i could produce at least the output like any one of the examples above using shell command. (Modified csv file), it would be fine. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Originally, you were pasting two files together. You could just shuffle (`shuf`) the `1.csv` and then paste that with `2.csv`.

Comment: Please ignore two csv files that i mentioned earlier, I want to shuffle the columns within the same csv file (R3.CSV), is (shuf) the shell command? Can you please assist me with the exact shell command to shuffle the individual column of the CSV and produce Modified.csv file like i mentioned above ?

Comment: Then `cut` the file apart, shuffle the column you want to shuffle, then `paste` the columns back together. You have the tools. Just put them together.

Comment: ok, yes, tried that, however while shuffling it shuffles the column header, is there a way to shuffle only the contents of the csv and not the csv header? meanwhile i used cut -d, -f3 < test.csv | sed '1d' > final.csv (to remove header) then shuf, however i need column headers to be added ,is there a way to insert column headers ?

Comment: You can copy the header line from the original data file.

Comment: Can you please help me with shell command to copy the header from the original file and insert that to the modified shuffled file?

Comment: Use the `head` command. That plus `cut`, `shuf`, and `paste` are all you need.